# MATLAB generate a surface from data points at angles

Tags: matlab

new to matlab here. 
I have 10 data points going from 0 to 90 in increments of 10 degrees between XY axes,  another 10 points in same increments for YZ and ZX. I want to create a surface from these points. I'm thinking I should define this in spherical coordinates and then convert to Cartesian, but I'm not sure how to assign a position to those data points for every plane. Currently I have

```
th = [0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90].*(2*pi)./360;
phi = [0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90].*(2*pi)./360;
r = [1.47 1.24 1.44 1.39 1.34 1.29 1.24 1.19 1.18 1.16] % r is my data at length 1.47 etc. from the origin in x to y plane
 x=r.*sin(th).*cos(phi);
  y=r.*sin(th).*sin(phi);
   z=r.*cos(th); 
[x,y,z]=sph2cart(th,phi,r);
plot3(x,y,z,'.');
grid on;
```

This is the best I can come up with. This spreads the rs across the whole graph instead of keeping them to XY plane and using other sets for YZ and ZX. I was thinking of creating separate sets a for x, b for y, c for z

```
a = [1.47 1.24 1.44 1.39 1.34 1.29 1.24 1.19 1.18 1.16] 
b = [2.47 2.24 .......................................] 
c = [5.01 4.95........................................]
     x=a.*sin(th).*cos(phi);
      y=b.*sin(th).*sin(phi);
       z=c.*cos(th);
```

However in this case I'm not sure how to fit a,b,c into `sph2cart(th,phi,r);`. This also  does not generate a surface, it just plots the points on every plane. I've tried to use mesh but I couldn't get it to work. Help is much appreciated, I'm very new to coding.

Comment: Hey there, trying checking out this link:http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/representing-a-matrix-as-a-surface.html . Go to the bottom and check out how you might be able to use surf with this data.

Comment: Could you try to be a bit more specific about the surface you're trying to plot? Can you give, for instance, an `r(theta,phi)` function and ranges for `theta` and `phi`? You should be able to generate a `theta,phi` mesh, then plot the corresponding polar points together with `r(theta,phi)`, but I need to understand if this is what you actualy want to achieve.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I don't really have a formula as it's lab data. I measured periods of a body suspended on a bifilar pendulum rotated about every axis for angles  0° through 90°every 10°. So I have 10 different r's for when it was rotated around x axis - r(10°), r2(20°) etc; another 10 different r's for rotation around y axis and another 10 r's for rotation around z.  I want to "connect the dots" and get a surface that hopefully resembles an ellipsoid.

Comment: In other words, in XY plane I have 10 lines of different lengths starting at the origin, making 10° angles between one another and 0 through 90° angles with the x axis. Same situation for YZ and ZX planes. Does that clarify things?

Comment: I think it does. So you have (roughly?) 3*10 points, 10 along each of the slices of an ellipsoid with the XY, YZ and ZX planes. The problem is that "connecting the dots" is far from straightforward in this case. Do you have an idea on pen-and-paper how you should construct the ellipsoid from these data?

Comment: My point is that you probably imagine a soap bubble's minimal surface that spans your dataset. Problem is, that's far from trivial to construct:) Well, as a first approximation you can create a convex hull with `convhull`...